# jQuery getting id with [id^=''] when i using ajax and fill and create table after that

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

in jQuery i'm using ajax and after getting data from that i create simple `table` with this data, for example

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/analyzePage/searchTag/' + tagName,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (data.state == 'error') {
                ...
            }
            else {
                let table = '<div class="table-responsive pre-scrollable">';

                ...

                $.each(data.tags, function (key, value) {
                    ...
                    table = table + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon btn-rounded legitRipple" id="searchTag-' + value.name + '">';
                    table = table + '<i class="icon-file-plus"></i>';
                    table = table + '</button>';
                    table = table + '</td>';
                    table = table + '</tr>';
                });

                ...

                $('.data').html(table);
            }
        }, 800);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

in this code and into `$.each` i add simple `<button>` with this id `id="searchTag-"' + value.name + '`.

now my question is how can i get this id with jquery? parent `.data` class is `div` with `searchHashTag` id as:

my below jquery code doesn't work and i can't get id from added `button`s

```
$("[id^='searchTag']").on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]);
});
```

Comment: Once this is rendered, right click on the button, and _Inspect_ it. You'll see the problem right away. Your quotes are misplaced. Your jQuery selector is correct.

Comment: @blex i dont get any error

Comment: I'm not talking about errors. I'm telling you to look at what your HTML actually looks like :)

Comment: @blex thanks. i fix simple bug in creating html table, but after fix that click on button don't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are loaded dynamically. Most likely, you are declaring the `click` event handler before the elements actually exist on the page, therefore, it does not find them. You can solve this in two ways.

**Method 1**

Add the click handler only when the elements exist:

```
// Inside your ajax callback (every time new buttons are added)
$('.data').html(table);
$("[id^='searchTag']").on('click', function () {/*...*/});
```

**Method 2** *(I would recommend this one)*

Use *event delegation*. It will bind the click event on an existing ancestor element, and work on any button you add later:

```
// Anywhere you want, but it needs to be executed only once
$(document).on('click', "[id^='searchTag']", function(){/*...*/});
```

Method 2 is preferred, because with method 1, for example if you have a `Load more` button which adds new buttons while keeping the ones loaded before, the latter ones will execute the click handler multiple times.

Note that using `document` as the ancestor element is safe because we know it always exist when your code is executed, but it would be better *(perfomance wise)* if you used a more precise container which already exists in your HTML. If that is the case for your `.data` container, then you should use `$('.data').on('click', '[id^...`. (Again, only execute this once).

Comment: could you help me on this topic `https://stackoverflow.com/q/50892269/1830228` ? thanks